# Could you reduce the weight of a Santa Cruz Chameleon down from 12.82 kg to 10kg (2018 model)?

Tags: mountain-bike, weight

I am currently thinking of getting my first mountain bike, I have ridden a lot of cyclocross and am used to a 10kg bike but am not that familiar where you could save weight on a mountain bike.

What components would you use to reduce the weight of a 2018 Santa Cruz Chameleon which currently retails at 12.82 kg? I would mostly be riding rough cyclocross races and XC races. I would be purchasing a large frame size.

Comment: Simplest, cheapest and healthiest is to lose 2.82 kg off your body.

Comment: this is a fair comment, I could lose the weight but am also curious if mountain bikes can hit this easily or if its not possible. my knowledge about part weights is very limited.

Comment: I ve seen a santa Cruz MTB (hard tail , front suspension) weighing in @6.935 kg (don't know the model, just seen the pics) https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=2189108567981676&id=2059707647588436

Comment: https://www.santacruzbicycles.com/en-US/highball-29 pay your money, take your choice

Comment: Note that the weight is also dependent on the bike size (I'd guess a medium). If you want to get a 10 kg mountain bike, you can, but you're going to be paying for it; the specialized epic hard tail seems to be under 8 kg for some sizes, though you'll be paying out the nose for it (not claiming its necessarily a compatible choice with your riding/budget, but it is possible to go ridiculously light on a complete bike).

Comment: @DanielRHicks its a pretty big assumption that an active cyclocross racer has 2.8kg to lose.  Most people interested in racing (here in the UK at least) are already in very good shape.

Comment: @Batman pity that ridiculously light implies ridiculously expensive ..

Comment: You are looking at a LOT of cash to get a Chameleon down to 10kg.  But assuming you are going to be using it for XC purposes, you can probably save close to 0.5kg just on the tyres.  It also probably comes as standard with tubes, so you can save another ~200g going tubeless.

Comment: @DanielRHicks When the Snickers bars your workmate puts out on her desk stare at you all day, losing weight does not feel like the "simplest" option.

Comment: Easiest way to lose bike weight is to "add money"  by replacing steel with CF or titanium.    How deep is your wallet?  Seriously - what's the available budget for this ?

Comment: Easiest way to lose bike weight on a bike that you don't even own yet is to buy a different bike that is already light enough.

Answer (score 23):

Breaking the rules with a kind-of non-answer and personal opinion, but...

1) Mountain bikes *should* be heavier than a cyclocross bike. It's got a suspension fork and frame and wheels need to be beefier to handle bigger loads and impacts.

2) Don't buy a bike with a plan replace major components. Just buy the bike that meets your needs in the first place (in this case a bike lighter than 12kg out of the box). Doing so will be much, much cheaper than swapping out parts.

Another way of stating (2) is: there is only one component you need to swap out for a lighter alternative - the bike itself.

I note the higher level SC Highball S hits your weight goal.

Answer (score 12):

Bontrager's Law states parts can be light weight, durable, or inexpensive you only get to pick two characteristics. The only time it makes  monetary sense to replace a part with a lighter one is if the component has failed. If you think 3kg. will make a difference between winning and losing try this experiment. Ride a timed course while carrying 2 full water bottles (approx. 1.5 kg) . Then ride the same timed course with out the bottles. Is the time difference greater than the time difference of the rider who finished before you. My point is that for the most elite athletes 3kg can be the difference between placing 1st or 15th. For most of us our times will vary more from conditioning variables than 3kg of weight.

Comment: Everything you said is true, but regardless of actual timings, a 10kg MTB 'feels' so much nicer when climbing or when making sudden bursts of power to clear step ups etc.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question, you'd change the fork and wheels, probably the seat post. Beyond that, you work down the list of diminishing returns through group set, going tubeless, bars, removing rotor bolts (!!) etc. until you get to <10kg. This would take a lot of money for exotic parts.

However, I think you've chosen the wrong bike. The Chameleon is not necessarily designed for <10kg XC racing. As others have noted, you're better off looking at the Highball, which is more XC than aggressive/trail.

Comment: I completely support losing 3kg off a mountain bike - this will make a big difference to how it rides and climbs well below the elite level.

Comment: You could even argue OP has chosen the wrong brand.  You can get a lot more bike for the money if it doesn't have a SC badge on it.

Answer (score 2):

I own a 2018 chameleon. The frame is light. You could save weight on the wheelset with carbon hoops, lighter tires, lighter cassette. You could also get carbon bars and a carbon seatpost. It would be expensive and sort of silly.